# Conditionals without actually using any conditional statements?

Tags: java, math

I'm taking an entry-level Java course and our first homework has me stumped, mostly because of how inconvenient the requirements make it.

> The output y shall be equal to two times the value of the input x if such input is an integer number between 0 and 4, inclusive.
>
> The output y shall be equal to the value of the input x if such input is an integer number between 5 and 9, inclusive.
>
> The output y shall be equal to 0 if the input x is an integer number between 10 and 14, inclusive.
>
> The code MUST NOT make use of "if" statements, "switch-case" statements, "for" loops, "while" loops, Boolean variables, or Boolean expressions

How would I do this without actually using conditional statements?

Comment: Just for context, what's the title of the chapter, lecture, section?

Comment: That is a toughie. I'm leaning towards something fancy with modulus division. Heh, or bitwise OR masks on the binary of the values..

Comment: I have a vague recollection of having heard a similar assignment awhile back. Is this from a popular textbook?

Comment: This can be trivially solved with a lookup table: `int[] lookupTable = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; return lookupTable[x];`

Comment: `int y = x * (2 - (x / 5));`

Comment: title of course is fundamentals of programming.

Comment: What should the result be if `x` is negative or greater than 14?

Comment: @FredLarson What if it's not a number?

Comment: @shmosel: Also a valid question.

Comment: @FredLarson I beg to differ.

Comment: @FredLarson: As we all know, specs are always perfect; if it's not in the spec, it cannot happen ;-)

Comment: @shmosel I tested that and it worked. If you add that as an answer, I'd be glad to upvote.

Comment: @FredLarson I believe it is assumed to be an integer between 0 and 14.

Comment: @shmosel I think this is the correct answer.  Thank you so much.  May I ask how you were able to solve it so quick?

Comment: This sounds like the torture our teacher used on us in 10th grade in "IT-class" when we were supposed to learn programming... *meh* :D @shmosel Your solution is actually quite elegant. I'd also like to know how you got there.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I looked for a pattern and found one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That could be an answer as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a simple math equation:

```
int y = x * (2 - (x / 5));
```

Comment: I like this, this is clever. +1

Comment: just to be sure, I would put `...((int)x / 5)`

Comment: If you want my upvote, you'll need to explain why this works.